# Python Certificate Verification

Tags: python, ssl, ssl-certificate

Lets start from the beginning.

I have a package that connects to Jira over API, and this package is called `pyJira`.

When I installed this package with `pip install --upgrade git+ssh://git@bitbucket.xxx.com:7999/pyt/pyjira` and the download was done, pip wasn't working right. This was fixed by removing `python-certifi-win32-init.pth` and `This package patches certifi at runtime to also include certificates from the windows certificate store`.

well now I was able to run my PyJira test script, but I then again got an error saying stuff like `[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self-signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:997)`.

I then fixed this by adding `"verify=False" in the request.get(URL, verify)`, but due to firewall I get this error

```
connectionpool.py:1043: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made to host 'jirabd.xxx.com'. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/1.26.x/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
warnings.warn(
....
```

So to me, it looks like there is some kind of a `certificate verification` problem throughout all this, but I have no idea where to look now since this took very long to figure out in the first place. Have anyone ever experienced this, and have a solution?

Comment: The solution is generally (a) figure out what CA is being used to sign the remote certificate and then (b) make sure that the appropriate CA certificate is installed wherever Python is looking for CA certificates. It sounds to me like removing `python-certifi-win32-init.pth` was the wrong solution to your earlier problem, since this was exposing the Windows certificate store to Python. Without that, you're probably missing most common CA certificates.

Comment: So I think is somthing to do with some package versioning, I copied the whole `site-package` from a working machine with all the certifi files etc, and now this machine also works. So I'm gonna do a `pip freeze > requirements.txt` for both `working/not site-package` to check their versions, and see which version has this error

Answer (score 0):

By removing `python-certifi-win32-init.pth` the functionality of the library is effectively lost with doing so. This is in relation to how the library monkey-patches the runtime to access the windows cert store.

Andrew Leech, the author of `python-certifi-win32`, [suggests to move on](https://gitlab.com/alelec/python-certifi-win32/-/issues/14#note_876668521) to his other project [pip-system-certs](https://gitlab.com/alelec/pip-system-certs) . Drop-in replacing the library with `pip-system-certs` ([PyPI link](https://pypi.org/project/pip-system-certs/)) solved all issues for me.